# Same Table used in Foreign Keys

Tags: sql, entity-framework

We're using Entity Framework, model rendered from a database.

In the database, we have a table, which has two foriegn keys to the another table.

So:

```
CREATE TABLE TABLEB
(
  id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
  somefields INT 
)

CREATE TABLE TABLEA
(
  id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
  currentTableAId INT NOT NULL,
  previousTableAId INT NULL

  CONSTRAINT fk_1 FOREIGN KEY (currentTableAId)  REFERENCES TableB (id),
  CONSTRAINT fk_2 FOREIGN KEY (previousTableAId )  REFERENCES TableB (id),

)
```

Problem is, Entity Framework calls the accociation in the TABLEA table 'TableB' and 'TableB1'.

Is there any way to make it call the reference 'CurrentTableA' and 'PreviousTableA'? At the moment, we manually go to the model in EF, and rename it. But, as we're generating a few times as we develop the database, this is a manual task. I was hoping there might be a hint or something on the FK that might tell EF to rename the relationship?

Comment: you can configure them via fluent api. here's a guide [Configuring/Mapping Properties and Types with the Fluent API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591617#Introduction) and [Configuring Relationships with the Fluent API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/data/jj591620)